# Solutions manual for Analysis On Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation

A few months ago,I wanted to learn something fundmental about manifolds. From highly recommend , I decided to choice *Analysis on Manifolds* by James R.Munkres as my self-learning textbook.Until now ,I have finished the first two chapter's solutions. But I am not sure my answer to this exerices abusolutly right.Is there   some solutions manual for this book? Can anyone  provides free downloads ?  I appreciate it indeed!

Comment: I don't think there is any official solution manual, but perhaps someone has made a document with solutions online somewhere. One thing that books in more advanced topics often do is just that; they leave out solutions. While it can be annoying to not be able to directly verify your solutions, this is mostly done for two reasons. 1) The author knows that teachers will want to give the problems in the book as homework to students. 2) A student at that level should now be trained to be independent of any solution manual, as he/she is supposed to one day stand on his/her own legs "in the wild".

Comment: But feel free to pose your questions here on this site if you want. You'll probably get your answers and hints.

Answer (score 6):

As of July 2017, one can find some detailed solutions of some problems from chapters 4-6 in: Herman Jaramillo, "Solution to selected problems of Munkres Analysis on Manifolds Book," at:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-200981706290/wufu/573279464f6e8

I will attach the file here if Stack permits attachments. Hmm, apparently not.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested, I wrote down solutions to all exercises in Chapters 1 and 2 (The Algebra and Topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Differentiation).

You can find them here: https://positron0802.wordpress.com/analysis-on-manifolds-munkres/

Comment: It's very useful, Thanks!