# Multivariable analysis books/online notes recommedation with solutions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, book-recommendation

I am studying differentiation on $\mathbb{R^n}$ with Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds book, but there are no solutions this book. Could you recommend problem sheets with solutions about differentiation on $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Thanks.

Comment: You have asked the forbidden question in this site..:p

Comment: @MariosGretsas hmm I'm sorry. Why ban?

Comment: We do not recommend solutions manuals here..it will be better for you if you worked the exercises alone,and posting here your whole attempt to check it and give you hints whenever you are stuck.

Comment: how about calculus on manifolds, this post will also be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659512/solutions-manual-for-analysis-on-manifolds?rq=1

Comment: @DonlansDonlans Thanks!